# if mysql field empty

Tags: php, mysql

i have menu from database.

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT id, menu FROM myTable WHERE showing='1' ORDER BY id ASC"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
$menu='';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $id = $row["id"];
    $hormenu = $row["menu"];
    $menu .='<li><a href="mypage.php?id='.$id.'">'. $hormenu .'</a></li>';
     }
```

when i keep any menu field empty.
it shows me

```
<li><a href="mypage.php?id='.$id.'"></a></li>
```

how could i hide or disable it

Any help Plzz.

Comment: Are you sure?  Why would it show that?  Can you provide the value of $row['menu'] and what HTML you'd like it to generate?

Comment: i have type this by mistake <li><a href="mypage.php?id='.$id.'"></a></li> Actualy it is <li><a href="mypage.php?id=1"></a></li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if it has any data

```
$hormenu = $row["menu"];
if($hormenu){
    $menu .='<li><a href="mypage.php?id='.$id.'">'. $hormenu .'</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    if (!empty($row["menu"]))
        $menu .='<li><a href="mypage.php?id='.$row["id"].'">'. $row["menu"] .'</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If "when i keep any menu field empty" means that the row in database has `NULL` or `''` value then just do not select such rows, ie to exclude rows where `menu` field is empty add `(menu <> '')AND(menu IS NOT NULL)` to your query's `WHERE` clause. So your SQL would be

```
SELECT id, menu FROM myTable WHERE(showing='1')AND(menu <> '')AND(menu IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY id ASC
```

Althought it would probably be better not to save such (invalid?) rows into database at all.